# Looping through a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am new to VBA and am trying to learn the nuances of code but have a project that I'm working on.

I need to loop through all fields of Column A and based on each different value (several 1's, a couple of 2's, one 3, etc.), copy the row-less column A, to the new template document.  I then need to loop through the same column of each of 2 additional spreadsheets in the same workbook and add to the template in specific fields based on the values in Column A.  I hope that makes sense.  So far I have this coding, starting with dim'ing my workbooks, sheets, etc. and activating the current workbook and template and sheet 1 "SCHOOLS' for the first.  It seems to be working so far but when I get to 'For x = 7', (the first row with data in my sheet is row 7), it is giving me a 424 object required error.

I have seen the talent of vba coders on this forum and am hoping that someone can help me?  Please see my code so far below:

```
Sub NewFormPerSchool()

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Ws5 As Worksheet

Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Rem For Each w In wbCurrent.Worksheets: MsgBox "'" & w.Name & "'": Next
Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\VBA\Wendie\6.9\Working\~TEMPLATE.xlsm")

Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("SCHOOLS")
With Ws1
For x = 7 To Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        Set wbTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        wbTarget.myName = Ws.Cells(x, 8).Value
        Sheets.FillAcrossSheets Ws.Range("1:7")
        Ws.Rows(x).Copy curWS.Range("B29")
    Next x
End With
```

Can someone help me?  And if you can explain what you do, I would appreciate it.  Again, I'm still learning and this is a great chance for me to learn from you. Thank you

I was expecting this code to loop through all of column A and find the number there (can be multiple rows of the same number) and then copy all other fields in those rows to a new template sheet.  Meaning, if column A shows '1', then the code should find all '1' rows and copy column B through the end of the row, and paste it into the template which is, in this upload, labeled 'sample'.  (I have moved this document out as a separate file, within the same folder as my data worksheet, and named it ~Template.  That is how I will use it for the future.)

Once completing copying and pasting the data from the 'SCHOOLS' data worksheet, it should then go to the 'XXXXX' spreadsheet within my active workbook and copy the rows, with the same number as above (1) and paste to the template.  Once this has been done for all '1' rows, I then need the file saved as the value of B29 in the template, saved, and closed.  Next I need the code to go to the beginning and find the '2' rows and do all the same, and then the '3' rows, etc.  This will result in the creation of approximately 300 separate workbooks.

I have tried searching through stack overflow, reading anything that seemed as it might be helpful to my situation, and also other google searches through other forums and have had no luck.  If it would be helpful, I have created a redacted file that should give an idea of what I'm looking at but someone will have to tell me how to upload the file here.

Comment: 1.) Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module. 2.) I told you twice before, to reference the workbook containing this code use `Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook`. There is no other way! 3.) `myName` is not an existing property but you cannot rename a workbook anyway. You need to use a worksheet variable: `Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet 1")` (are you sure about the space?). What's that *"several 1's, a couple of 2's, one 3, etc."* supposed to mean? What's with columns 7 (`G`) and 8 (`H`) and cell `B29`? What are you doing with `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets`?

Comment: Add any additional information to your post. Also, add the screenshots of worksheet `"SCHOOLS"` and worksheet `Sheet 1`. BTW `Spreadsheet` is a word that is usually not used in the context of VBA and means the file (workbook). In VBA, use *workbook* (file) and *worksheet*.

Comment: @VBasic2008, please see my attached document to explain the additional part. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. However, as you can see in that document, I need to loop through the worksheet and copy all rows with 1 to a template document, then my code will take it to another worksheet and copy all rows with 1 to the template, then another... Next I need the code to do the same with a new template with all 2's, and another new template for all 3's, etc. I have a total of 309 templates that I need to create

Comment: Here's a new link to my file, I hope this one will work?  The 'Template' file is included in the workbook as a separate worksheet, although that file will be a separate workbook completely, not a worksheet.  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8je43oogktrkk3wgwafkd/Schools-VBA-to-template.xlsm?rlkey=pwnslk6faptc6gaopk06u421d&dl=0

Comment: OK, you can try is that what you need? watch your inbox, I've replied to you. Just run `NewFormPerSchool` in Module1 to see. If that's Plz tell me, I'll paste the code here and you accept my answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave is not complete, and the description of the situation does not quite match, I can only answer the problems with your current code, see the comment text in the code for details.

```vb
Sub NewFormPerSchool()
    Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, curWS As Worksheet
    
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
    
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws5 As Worksheet
    
    Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Rem you lost set this :
    Set curWS = wbCurrent.ActiveSheet
    
    Rem For Each w In wbCurrent.Worksheets: MsgBox "'" & w.Name & "'": Next
    Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\VBA\Wendie\6.9\Working\~TEMPLATE.xlsm")
    'just for my test
    'Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\oscar\Dropbox\VS\stackoverflow\VBA\test.xlsm")
    
    Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("SCHOOLS")
    'Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets(1) 'just for my test
    
    With Ws1
    
    Rem your "Ws1" was wrong to "ws", losted the "1".
    'For x = 7 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 7 To Ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    
            Set wbTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
            wbTarget.myName = ws.Cells(x, 8).Value
            Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:7")
            ws.Rows(x).Copy curWS.Range("B29")
        Next x
    End With
    
    '...
    
End Sub
```

> I have created a redacted file that should give an idea of what I'm looking at but someone will have to tell me how to upload the file here.

You should attach a sample, otherwise, there is no way to reproduce the situation you are experiencing. You can upload it to the cloud, and share that link here for the answerer to download it for reference.

### 20230712

Your code has a big problem. You should put `Option Explicit` on the top of your `Mudule1`, This prevents you from forgetting to declare a variable, misspelling a variable name, or misusing a variable. These are big problems in your code.

[image]

### 20230714

```vb
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Option Explicit

Sub NewFormPerSchool()

    Dim x As Long
    
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'ie. Dest workbook
    Dim wbCurrent As Workbook 'ie. Source workbook
    
    Rem You only need to have two sheet variables, one is the source and the other is the destination
    Rem because when you switch to another sheet, you can just use the original variable and re-set its value.
    Dim WsSoruce As Worksheet
    Dim WsDest As Worksheet
    'Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    'Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    'Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
    'Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
    'Dim Ws5 As Worksheet
    
    
    Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
    Rem For Each w In wbCurrent.Worksheets: MsgBox "'" & w.Name & "'": Next
    'Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\VBA\Wendie\6.9\Working\~TEMPLATE.xlsm")
    
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596987/looping-through-a-spreadsheet
    Rem Because you 'have moved this document out as a separate file, within the same folder as my data worksheet, and named it ~Template.
    'Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbCurrent.Path + "\~TEMPLATE.xlsm")
    
    Rem file name cell:'need the file saved as the value of B29 in the template'
    Dim savedFileNameCell As Range, savedFileNameCellRow As Long
    
    Rem Get data scope
    Dim rowCntr As Long, columnCntr As Integer
    Dim cRangeStart As Range, i As Long
    Dim pasteStartRow As Long 'paste starting with this row index
    pasteStartRow = 1
    
    'the row index your data start
    Dim dataStartRow As Integer
    dataStartRow = 7
    
    Rem stop screen refresh
    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Rem get the number to process
    Dim dictNum As Object 'New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key
    Set dictNum = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Rem sort WsSoruce by column A
    sortWorkSheet wbCurrent.Sheets("SCHOOLS"), dataStartRow - 1
    Rem get the number to process
    getNumber2Process_SourceSorted wbCurrent.Sheets("SCHOOLS"), 1, rowCntr, dictNum

    
    savedFileNameCellRow = 29 'District 1 School 1':'need the file saved as the value of B29 in the template'
    Set savedFileNameCell = wbCurrent.Sheets("Sample").Cells(savedFileNameCellRow, 2)
    
    Rem process every number
    For Each key In dictNum
        Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbCurrent.Path + "\~TEMPLATE.xlsm")
        Rem thru all sheets in wbCurrent except Sample
        Rem 'I then need to loop through the same column of each of 2 additional spreadsheets in the same workbook and add to the template in specific fields based on the values in Column A. '
        Rem If there are only 2 other sheets have to do, then you have to specify them
        For Each WsSoruce In wbCurrent.Worksheets
            
            'Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("SCHOOLS")
            If WsSoruce.Name <> "Sample" Then 'exclude the sheet Sample
                    
                    'rowCntr = WsSoruce.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    rowCntr = WsSoruce.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    columnCntr = WsSoruce.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    
                    Rem sort WsSoruce by column A, only do once
                    If key = 1 Then
                        If WsSoruce.Name <> "SCHOOLS" Then ' sheet "SCHOOLS" already sorted before
                            sortWorkSheet WsSoruce, dataStartRow - 1
                        End If
                    End If
                            
                    
                    Rem fill the target sheet with header
                    'wbTarget.Sheets.FillAcrossSheets WsSoruce.Range("1:" & dataStartRow - 1) 'when wbTarget only has 1 sheet, you can do this
                    Rem set the target sheet to paste to
                    Set WsDest = wbTarget.Sheets(1)
                    Range(WsSoruce.Cells(1, 1), WsSoruce.Cells(dataStartRow - 1, columnCntr)).Copy WsDest.Cells(pasteStartRow, 1)
                    If pasteStartRow = 1 Then
                        pasteStartRow = dataStartRow
                    Else
                        pasteStartRow = pasteStartRow + dataStartRow - 1
                    End If
                    
                    With WsSoruce 'Ws1
                        x = dataStartRow
                        Do While WsSoruce.Cells(x, 1).Value <= key And x <= rowCntr
                        'For x = dataStartRow To rowCntr Step 1
                        'For x = 7 To WsSoruce.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
                            Rem record the beginning of the range
                            If WsSoruce.Cells(x, 1).Value = key And cRangeStart Is Nothing Then
                                Set cRangeStart = WsSoruce.Cells(x, 2) ''copy the row-less column A'
                                If savedFileNameCell Is Nothing Then Set savedFileNameCell = cRangeStart
                            End If
                            'If i = 0 Then
'                                i = WsSoruce.Cells(x, 1) 'the num to do
'                            ElseIf i <> WsSoruce.Cells(x, 1) Then
                                'Range(cRangeStart, WsSoruce.Cells(x - 1, columnCntr)).Copy WsDest.Cells(pasteStartRow, 2)
'                                i = WsSoruce.Cells(x, 1)
                                'pasteStartRow = pasteStartRow + (x - cRangeStart.Row)
'                            End If
                            'Set wbTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
                            'wbTarget.myName = wbTarget.Cells("F29").Value
                            'ws.Rows(x).Copy wbTarget.Range("B29")
                        'Next x
                            x = x + 1
                        Loop
                        x = x - 1
                        Range(cRangeStart, WsSoruce.Cells(x, columnCntr)).Copy WsDest.Cells(pasteStartRow, 2)
                        pasteStartRow = pasteStartRow + (x - cRangeStart.Row + 1)
                        x = 0
                        Set cRangeStart = Nothing
                    End With
                        
                    'Set wbTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
                    pasteStartRow = pasteStartRow + 2
                    
            End If
        Next WsSoruce
        
        savedFileNameCellRow = savedFileNameCellRow + 1 'District 1 School 2 ...
        
        Rem You need to ensure that the file does not exist. Otherwise, you need to add judgment to prevent errors when saving files
        Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'wbTarget.SaveAs wbTarget.Path + "\" + savedFileNameCell.Value + ".xlsm"
        wbTarget.SaveAs VBA.Replace(wbTarget.FullName, "~Template", savedFileNameCell.Value)
        wbTarget.Close
        Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        pasteStartRow = 1
        Set savedFileNameCell = Nothing
    Next key
    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'resume screen refresh
'    MsgBox "done!", vbInformation
    Shell "explorer.exe " + wbCurrent.Path, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub


Sub sortWorkSheet(ws As Worksheet, HeaderRowCount As Byte)
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add key:=ws.Range("A" & HeaderRowCount + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        '.SetRange Range("A7:G100")
        .SetRange ws.Range("A" & HeaderRowCount + 1, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count))
        '.SetRange Range(ws.Cells(HeaderRowCount + 1, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count))
        .Header = xlNo 'xlYes
        '.MatchCase = False
        '.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        '.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub


Sub getNumber2Process_SourceSorted(ws As Worksheet, column As Integer, rowCntr As Long, ByRef dict As Object) ', ByRef dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(column).Cells 'Range("A:A")
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict(cell.Value) = 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the link to my redacted file:  https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=schools-vba-to-template

Comment: VBasic2008, please see my attached document to explain the additional part.  I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  However, as you can see in that document, I need to loop through the worksheet and copy all rows with 1 to a template document, then my code will take it to another worksheet and copy all rows with 1 to the template, then another...  Next I need the code to do the same with a new template with all 2's, and another new template for all 3's, etc.  I have a total of 309 templates that I need to create

Comment: @Kristen You should add `@` before "*VBasic2008*" to mention him in the comments below your post. He will not be notified if you respond in this way. These two days I am busy, free to come back to see it. Thank you for sharing. Forgive me.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, Oscar Sun.  I didn't know that.  I will see if it will let me edit it and do that.

Comment: @Kristen You should add this comment under your post, not mine. Good luck！ Because *VBasic2008* did not reply here. And when you type `@` and "V" after it, it should show a prompt to select or type Tab key to apply that name.

Comment: Sorry about that...  I'm new here, did I mention that  LOL  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Kristen I can't read it:`You need additional access
You must gain additional access to the Project: schools-vba-to-template
To request access, please contact the Project Administrator and provide the following information:

Troubleshooting information:
   Subject: oscarsun72@gmail.com
   Source: schools-vba-to-template
   Troubleshooting URL: console.cloud.google.com/iam-...

Missing or denied permissions:
   storage. buckets. list`

Comment: @Kristen In addition to the sample, it would be better to attach a sample of the results you want, so that we can be sure of the results you want because it is a bit abstract and complicated to hear your description!

Comment: Sun - would you please explain how I contact the administrator with this information?

Comment: @Kristen I don't know, could you share your sample somewhere like Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, etc.?

Comment: Sun, I have added Option Explicit to the top of my coding and made a couple of other changes that were suggested, can I resubmit my code as it currently is for you to see?

Comment: @Kristen Not now. The most urgent thing is that you have to tell me what kind of Rows you want to take out from the worksheet *SCHOOLS*, and after copying them out, you want to paste them into a new WorkBook, that's all. is that so? Please revise your question to make these points clear. Thanks.

Comment: Sun - I have updated my original question, I hope that make more sense now?

Comment: @Kristen Good! That's more clear much. However, `paste it into the template` and `paste to the template`, where should I paste the two parts of data into the template *Sample*? Please add this to your original post. I'm going to be ready to implement it once this's confirmed.

Comment: @Kristen And did your sheets `XXXXX` and `SCHOOLS` can be sorted or already sorted by column A?

Comment: @Kristen "need the file saved as the value of B29 in the template," However, as I look at your B29 cell in Sample, it seems that it is not named according to the value of that cell, but according to the "School 1" that each number carries, so 2 is "District 2 School 1" and 3 is "District 3 School 1"...and so on. That's what name I saved them using, see if that's the way you want it. And I have sorted the source file before executing the copy facility. If you don't want to save it, then you can just choose not to save them after the end of the execution when closing the source file.

Comment: @Kristen If you do not want the source files to be sorted when the program is executed, please tell me again, and I will rewrite the code. I've replied to you, Plz watches your inbox, as I mention under your post.

Comment: Hello Oscar, so sorry I didn't respond earlier.  Yes, Column A will be sorted by number so all 1's should be together, all 2's together, etc.   For naming the files, yes, that would be correct and fine.  I simply need them named based on the values of the school name in the template file.

Comment: @Kristen did you receive my mail in your personal email? Have you tested my code and checked its result and generated files?

Comment: Hello Oscar, I did not get your email.  :(  I have been watching but it hasn't come through.

Comment: @Kristen OK, I send it again. Plz to watch. Alternatively, you can use the code I've posted here to apply it to the sample file you've given me for testing. It just is pasted from the file I sent you.  The mail's tile is "!Schools VBA to template" `Subject: Fwd: !Schools VBA to template`. Plz double check.